# How to maximize browser window with helium using Java?

Tags: java, automation, helium

I am trying to implement helium in my project, I checked the API doc of helium but I didn't find any commend to maximize the browser.

In the API doc I found solution to launch the browser. Code is as following

```
startFirefox();
startFirefox("google.com");
```

So I would appreciate if any one can help me with this. Is it possible to integrate Selenium and helium all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium WebDriver by integrating with Helium. The following code would work fine:

```
import static com.heliumhq.API.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

startFirefox("http://www.google.com");//This is the Helium code
getDriver().manage().window().maximize();//getDriver is Helium method and other portion is WebDriver code
```

Comment: Thanks ripon al wasim for the ans but is there any specific way to implement this using helium

Comment: Helium can be integrated with Selenium WebDriver. If you visit "heliumlib" folder you can see "selenium-java-2.45.0.jar" for supporting WebDriver. The method getDriver() of Helium returns the Selenium WebDriver and You can use it in some cases where there is no direct Helium support.